# How can i turn a image to a fullscreen preview in UIWebView

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, fullscreen

I'm using a UIWebView with text and picture in it.I want to do something like this: when I double tap the picture in the UIWebView, it will become a fullscreen preview model. Could anyone give me some advises or solutions ? Thx very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i have at the moment, set the UIWebViews Delegate to self then add this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *URL = [request URL];          
        ImageViewer *imageView = [[[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageViewer" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        imageView.imageURL = URL;
        [self presentModalViewController:imageView animated:YES];
        return NO; 
   } else {
        return YES;
   }
}
```

Just make the image a link in the html like you would normally. If you have other links that you don't want to load in a model then you can mod the code to detect if the link being pressed is going to an image otherwise just return YES;

I'm having a little problem with my webview which i have posted here (just incase you get the some problem!!) [UIWebView gets cleared after dismissing a fullscreen modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952047/uiwebview-gets-cleared-after-dismissing-a-fullscreen-modal)

Hope this helps!